# Do you know of any real life business application made on ASP.NET MVC (commercial)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does any one know about any real application built on asp.net MVC framework.  I am not
talking about opensource projects as I am pretty much aware of it.

I am more interested in knowing about any commercial website like banking, ecommerce
or any other line of business application that's built on this framework.

EDIT:
Clarification regarding opensource.  I am pretty much aware of opensource projects and they are great.  What I am looking for is commercial business application that's made on this framework.

Comment: you mean, other than stackoverflow.com?

Comment: Since when are open source projects not "real applications"? I consider MySQL, Apache, Firefox, etc. to be pretty "real".

Comment: Jason : Yes.  I am more interested in any commercial application like ecommerce, banking, brokerage etc...

Comment: ceejayoz : I think you haven't read my question. I had requested for commercial application. And it's my wish to filter out opensource application as that area I am  pretty much aware of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you visit [What is ASP.NET MVC?](http://www.asp.net/mvc/whatisaspmvc/) and scroll to the bottom there is a list of sites that use ASP.NET MVC including stackoverflow.com.

Comment: it seems page is not available

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, I have built a commercial "line of business" application on ASP.NET MVC 1.0.** We started development on the site when the framework was in beta; and released the site this summer. We are completely happy with our technology choice. Unfortunately I really can't say much more, as my employer would not welcome it.

I'm not sure about the OP's intent; **do you mean to get validation of the MVC pattern for very large codebases, i.e. 200 kloc or larger codebases?** I can't give you that, and I doubt anyone else really can right now, because there simply hasn't been time to develop so large codebases since the release of ASP.NET MVC. I would suggest researching MVC in Java, as this is probably where you'll find most older & large MVC deployments.

My usual counterargument to the 'very large codebase' fear is you simply shouldn't design so large monolithic apps anymore -- break up the responsibilities and use a SOA architecture to reduce complexity for each individual area of responsibility.

For a webapp on the .NET stack I'd select ASP.NET MVC again with complete confidence. That said, there are many other good choices in webapp frameworks these days.

Answer (score 0):

In here you can easily find **top 10** web sites that are built with ASP.NET.

http://www.findmyhosts.com/top-10-asp-net-mvc-framework-websites/